# Размытые границы у фотографии, используя CSS

Tags: css, вёрстка, изображения, blur

Как сделать границы border размытыми, не используя картинку? По идее, надо как-то преобразовать размытие всей картинки, но не могу придумать как:

```
img{
-webkit-filter: blur(20px); 
-moz-filter: blur(20px); 
filter: blur(20px);
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте использовать какой-нибудь готовый плагин вроде такого http://nbartlomiej.github.io/foggy/ или https://github.com/GianlucaGuarini/vague.js

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вот здесь реализовано кроссбраузерное отражение и размытие:
http://jsfiddle.net/_bop/CD3qv/7/

А здесь описано, как делали: http://webformyself.com/krossbrauzernye-otrazheniya-svecheniya-i-razmytiya-css/

Comment: костыль то ещё тот... ( но как говорится что есть то есть).... и с тегом body ... начудили

Comment: @shilgen с тегом body все окей. Только это стоило сделать с тегом html